# Unable to convert ''d/m/y h:m'' format into CST time format

Tags: r, datetime, time, timezone

I want to convert some character values into time format.
First I tried:

```
as.POSIXct('1/1/2010 04:00','%m/%d/%Y %H:%m','CST6CDT')
```

It returned `NA`.
Then I tried:

```
library(lubridate)
with_tz(as.POSIXct('1/1/2010 04:00','%m/%d/%Y %H:%m'),'CST6CDT')
```

It returned wrong value:

```
"0001-01-19 18:00:00 CST"
```

Why this happend and how to get the correct value:`"2010-01-01 04:00:00 CST"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lubridate`, it does work if we use the `dmy_hm` way

```
library(lubridate)
dmy_hm('1/1/2010 04:00', tz = 'CST6CDT')
#[1] "2010-01-01 04:00:00 CST"
```

---

Also, with `as.POSIXct`, there is a typo for minutes format.  It should be `%M`

```
as.POSIXct('1/1/2010 04:00', format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',tz = 'CST6CDT')
#[1] "2010-01-01 04:00:00 CST"
```

Comment: After a few tests, I think my problem comes from ignoring 'format=', I added it and then it works.

Comment: @YQ.Wang  Both are important, i.e. `format` call and the `%M` for minutes because if you look at the arguments in `?as.POSIXct`, the second argument is `tz`, followed by `format`, so without specifying it, it may think that the `tz` is the second argument and creates problems.

Comment: I see. Really appreciate your help!